# Evaluate or execute a string in sml

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm looking for a way to execute as string in sml. For example:

```
val evalResult = eval "1 + 1";
> val it = 2 : int
```

I can't actual believe that I didn't find any resource on this topic...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: SML, like most typed languages, does not have any eval. And although that would not be impossible, its absence is usually considered a feature. ;)